# How to safely removeObserver (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have added an observer

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"selector name", name: "observer name", object:nil)
    ...
}
```

When removing observer in deinit,

```
deinit
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: <some string>)
}
```

the app sometimes **crashes**:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   'Cannot remove an observer "class"
>   for the key path "some string" from
>   NSNotificationCenter because it is not registered as an
>   observer.

---

So I am trying to add do/catch

```
deinit
{
    do{
        try NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: <some string>)
    }catch{}
}
```

But I get a warning:

> catch block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in do block

**And the app crashes**

---

and when I am adding a try

```
deinit
{
    do{
        try NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: <some string>)
    }catch{}
}
```

I get this warning:

> no calls to throwing functions occur within try expresion

**And the app crashes**

How should that be done?

Comment: You must call `removeObserver()` only if you did call `addObserver()` before. *You* have to ensure that the calls are properly balanced.

Comment: cant you rewrite your code to use didSet instead of KVO ?

Comment: The solution to an exception like that (improperly calling a system API) is pretty much never to use a try block. As Martin said, balance your calls.

Comment: @MartinR I am calling addObserver. I have no idea why it is not registered :(((

Comment: @ogres I have to use KVO

Comment: Where/when is addObserver called? Please add the code.

Comment: @MartinR, I've updated the question with the code. tldr: in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use code

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

Explain: 
 You have mistake here: You are using NSNotification & NSNotificationCenter so you have to using this code above to remove observe.
 you have use code  for KVO to remove observer so it will wrong.

More detail you can read at here. [Key-Value-Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)

Comment: Can you expand on why `removeObserver(_:,forKeyPath:)` was the wrong method to use?

Answer (score 12):

If you support iOS Versions by 9.0 you don't need to remove observers by yourself in your `deinit` method.

Taken from the documentation

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and
>   NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to
>   registered observers that may be deallocated.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/

Comment: FYI This is the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver).

And be aware that it is the observer on NotificationCenter who will be removed by the system automatically.

Comment: @MichaelRevlis "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, and you used addObserver(_:selector:name:object:), you do not need to unregister the observer. If you forget or are unable to remove the observer, the system cleans up the next time it would have posted to it."